# Add a New Site to WordPress Multisites Network

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to add a new site  to my new multisite network but without success : 
when I add a new site, all seem to work correctly, I have a message that says that the site has been successfully created but when I click on the `visit` link I get a 404 error.

Moreover, nothing seems to be created in my files although it takes a pretty long time to create the new site.

I'm probably missing something but I have no idea of what I can do now, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i did this kind of things before. here are the tips to follow you debug:

before we start, We assume your multisite network is setup successfully.

setting up adding new site

1.Go to login main site wp-admin, which will lead you to network wp-admin then you can 
create new site by the build in wizard.

2.by creating a new site, it also auto create a set of cloned tables in your multisite shared Database
such as using diff prefix other than the default "wp_" for example the "wp_2_" , "wp_3_" etc by default. If you are not sure, just go phpmyadmin and see the changes and decide which table prefix you want to use.

3.creating new site don't mean creating files in the sub site path, you need to copy paste your wordpress files into the path you created.

4.You also need to change the .htaccess & wp-config of the new sub site properly , in wp-config, don't forget to point correct wordpress table prefix  (such as "wp_2_") of your new created site.

5.Go to the "option" table of your new created site (such as wp_2_option) to check whether the themes, the site_url, home_url etc are configured properly, otherwise you might see blank page when visiting your subsite path. (noted this setting also can be done in network wp-admin panel)

6.update database and login wp-admin to enable all deactivated plugins (as multisite will auto deactivate them initially so you may see a lot of error messages when plugin is not activated first.)

7.usually, after successfully creating the new sub site, you also need to do a proper table content migration to your new created site's tables, as because the new wordpress table created by multisite wp-admin panel only contains basic informations which can not display the whole features of the site you expected to display. 
  (do the sql migration just like you do in other single site wordpress migration, but using differnt table prefix. so you may find and replace urls/strings of the sql manually. )

Answer (score 0):

If just adding a new site via admin, and your installation is ok, steps 1 and 2 (in first answer) should suffice, check the extra database tables have been created in step 2, if that's not happened, something is awry with your installation, and I would suggest that's the first issue to resolve. You shouldn't have to look at .htaccess, wp-config.php, etc if everything is setup ok to simply add new sites.